# Get current tab's url via .batch file

Tags: firefox, batch-file

I'm Firefox guy, is there any way to get active tab's url via `.batch` file?

For example, if url of active tab in Firefox is `whatever.com`, I need to get `whatever.com` using `bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

Only the active tab will have a title detectable by `tasklist`. So:

```
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"  |findstr /r /v "N/A"
```

or processed with `FOR`:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=9* delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"  ^|findstr /r /v "N/A"') do @echo %%b
```

though the title could be different than the link.

With [**`sendkeys.bat`**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) you can trick the browser to change its title to the current link:

```
@echo off
::get the title of the active page
for /f "skip=3 tokens=9* delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"  ^|findstr /r /v "N/A nsAppShell:EventWindow"') do set "fftitle=%%b"
::get the first 10 sympols needs to be passed to the sendkeys command
set "fftitle=%fftitle:~0,10%"
::opens the console of the browser
call sendkeys.bat "%fftitle%" "{f12}"
::waits for 2 seconds
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:2 /dataonly /samples:2  1>nul
::changing the title with the link location
call sendkeys.bat "%fftitle%" "document.title=window.location.href{ENTER}"
::wait for 3 seconds
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:3 /dataonly /samples:2  1>nul
::get the new title
for /f "skip=3 tokens=9* delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"  ^|findstr /r /v "N/A nsAppShell:EventWindow"') do set "fftitle=%%b"
echo "%fftitle%"
```

**Edit**. Direct opening of the console:

```
@echo off
::get the title of the active page
for /f "skip=3 tokens=9* delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"  ^|findstr /r /v "N/A nsAppShell:EventWindow"') do set "fftitle=%%b"
::get the first 10 sympols needs to be passed to the sendkeys command
set "fftitle=%fftitle:~0,10%"
::opens the console of the browser
call sendkeys.bat "%fftitle%" "^+K"
::waits for 2 seconds
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:2 /dataonly /samples:2  1>nul
::changing the title with the link location
call sendkeys.bat "%fftitle%" "document.title=window.location.href{ENTER}"
::wait for 3 seconds
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:3 /dataonly /samples:2  1>nul
::get the new title
for /f "skip=3 tokens=9* delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"  ^|findstr /r /v "N/A nsAppShell:EventWindow"') do set "fftitle=%%b"
echo "%fftitle%"
```

Comment: Doesn't change the browser title in my tests. obviously I could not get the active tab's url too

Comment: @MehdiDehghani - is there any error printed?Does the the script open the console of the browser?

Comment: I got no error, the browser console got open by the script (_Network tab_ ), but the title doesn't changed.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani  - ahaaa. Firefox preserves last clicked tab.YOu can click the console tab and it will work.Meanwhile I'll alter the script to directly open the console

Comment: @MehdiDehghani - can you try my update?

Comment: Still title dosn't change, and active tab redirected to last active tab's url.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani - it works for me.May be you can try to increase the timeouts.Or try with different javascript line that will work on your machine.